# Pause collider in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I would like that collider is paused for few seconds at the beginning of the game. I'm using this script on object. Thanks.

```
 public class PickUpObject : MonoBehaviour {

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision Col)
{

    if (Col.gameObject.name== "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("collision detected");

        Destroy(gameObject);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: or disable the collider until so many seconds have passed

Comment: There used to be coroutines in Unity from what I remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a timer to check it.

```
public class PickUpObject : MonoBehaviour {
    public float timer = 10f; //seconds

    private void Update()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision Col)
    {
        if (Col.gameObject.name== "Player" && timer <= 0f)
        {
            Debug.Log("collision detected");

            Destroy(gameObject);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My prefered method would be to set a `_startTime` variable with the time the scene started and then use that to check against when needed rather than incremementing a value each frame in a `Update` method.

```
private float _delay = 2f;
private float _startTime;

private void Start()
{
    _startTime = Time.time;
}   

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    if(Time.time - _startTime < _delay)
    {
        //Exit if the time passed is less than the _delay
        return;
    }
    //Else run check against player
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("collision detected");

        Destroy(gameObject);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PickUpObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public float delayTime = 2.0f;
    public float currentTime = 0.0f;

    private void Update()
    {
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision Col)
    {
        if (Col.gameObject.name== "Player" && currentTime > delayTime)
        {
            delayTime += currentTime;

            Destroy(gameObject);

            delayTime -= currentTime;
            currentTime = 0.0f;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html
and check if it's bigger than 5 :D